# Vue tab change text color for active class

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to change the text color of the active tab.

*Using Vue.js + Vuetify*

I created an `.active` CSS class. The interesting part is that `background-color` property for active classes work, but the text color (color) doesnt change when active.

How should I change the code so that both properties apply for the active class ?

style

```
  .active {

  color: #222222;
  background-color: #ffff;
  }
```

template

```
      <v-tabs
        background-color="#FFFFEA"
        slider-color="#C89933"
        optional
        right
        active-class="active"

        >

        <v-tab
          class="normalize font-weight-bold "
          to="/tab1"
          >
          Tab 1
        </v-tab>          

        <v-tab    
          class="normalize font-weight-bold"
          to="/tab2"
          >
          Tab 2
        </v-tab>   

        <v-tab
          class="normalize font-weight-bold"
          to="/tab3"
          >
          Tab 3
        </v-tab>
  
          
      </v-tabs>
```

Comment: have you tried adding scoped property on the style tag?

Comment: scoped tag makes both `background-color` and `color` inactive.

Comment: Have you tried adding '!important' flag in css property?

Comment: @santanubera this solved the problem. Please add your comment as a reply so I can mark it as the correct solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default color comes from the Vuetify component itself. To override the color you can use *!important* flag after the color value.

```css
    .active {
       color: #222222 !important;
       background-color: #ffff !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your tabs route to a url link in which you can check your current $route.name and confirm it is the current active one. Use a ternary expression to choose the class to render. Do something like the below.

```
 <a
          @click="this.$router.push('http://localhost:8081/')"
          href="#"
          class="
            hover:bg-papaDark-700
            text-white
            hover:text-gray-200
           
          "
          :class="$route.name === 'Home' ? 'border-l-6 border-gray-200 ' : ''"
        >
```

In which 'Home' would be your route component name for 'locahost:8081/'. For example.

Tell me if it works

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using vue-router (with history mode).  I don't really understand how to implement your solution. Should I implement the ternary expression to v-tab ?

Comment: Yes. A ternary expression for the css class in each v-tab. In case $route.name returns true, the class that has whatever attribute will be rendered. I think you are using tailwind. If yes, use the same code of mine to test on any route component. If no, just place your class name instead of tailwind's attributes and do a small test on an active tab.

Comment: Pls mark as accepted if it worked for you